# Google Cloud Platform Cloud Run: Get Services Using the REST API

Tags: api, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to list all Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Run services for a project `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME` using the `namespaces.services.list` REST method (more on that method [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/list)).

However, when I replace `{endpoint}` with `asia-east1-run.googleapis.com` and `{parent}` with `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME`:

```sh
curl \
--request GET "https://asia-east1-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME/services" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"

#=>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  . . .
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  . . .
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME/services</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I get a `404`.  I have also tried the GCP project number instead of the project name with no luck.

Comment: 404 means the URI was not found. You are masking the real URI, so you will can only guess what endpoint you are calling (HTTP GET).

Comment: I still dont get you.. You mean the API url that i formed is incorrect ? If yes then where am i going wrong ? What should the correct API be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation that you share on the question you will see that the `{parent}` is:

> The namespace from which the services should be listed. For Cloud Run (fully managed), replace `{namespace_id}` with the project ID or number. It takes the form `namespaces/{namespace_id}`.

So the problem in your URL is that you are replacing `{parent}` for you `{projectID}` when in fact you should be replacing by `namespace/{projectID}`.

Also, an obvious thing but might as well say it, do not copy `https://` while adding the `https://asia-east1-run.googleapis.com` endpoint since the `https://` is already contained in the URL template.

Try it out and let me know if this solves the issue.